# How can i modify a dropdownlist to have buttons on each item row? and a textbox after the last row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I wish to modify the DDL to have a button on this far right of each item row where the user can remove that item by clicking on it.

I also wish to add a textbox to a row after the last item row where the user can type in anything then press an ADD button on the far right of said row to add this item to the list.

I would also like to have it update without having to close and reopen it.

---

I realize this may be hard but i am looking for pointer and tips to where to START. I have done nothing similar.

Might there be an already existing custom control with such specifications?

Comment: i didn't see ddl like this one. but i have an idea. you can work with ul tag in html and customize with css. it will work bro.

Comment: it will be more convinient if you use javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery or ajax.
if you want to use ajax you can simply use dropdownextender-->
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DropDown/DropDown.aspx

You can configure to display a gridview or panel with desired template and events.